# Custom pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a SP list called "Company" containing 6000 items.
Also I don't have access to central admin nor I have a site collection administrator permission(also no designer access).

I want to create a page like in the image attached using js.On page load I want to show first 100 items only and rest of items should be retrieved on clicking next/prev buttons.So suggest me suitable way to create a custom pagination using js.

[image]

Comment: You need to narrow this question down. It is way to broad to be answerable in a format suitable for this community

Comment: I have edited the question.Hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement custom pagination using knockout.js

I referred this url : http://www.sharepointyammertech.com/2014/11/sharepoint-2013-how-to-implement.html

**EDIT**
I was also able to create pagination using JSLink which I find more easier than the above one I referred.
I referred this [url](http://www.casvaniersel.com/2013/02/jslink-with-paging-for-rendering-list-views/)